# Change table row display property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html page with a table that contains a hidden row:

```
<table>
  <tr id="hiddenTr" style="display:none">
    ...
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need to make it visible at client side using jquery. I tried this

```
$('#hiddenTr').show();
```

and this

```
$('#hiddenTr').css('display', 'table-row');
```

Both implementations don't work for me. Furthemore the second one is not crossbrowser.

**UPD.**  Sorry, guys. That was my fault: I mistyped tr element id. That's strange $('hiddenTr') didn't return null...

Comment: If <TR> has no <TD> tag, how would you know that its visibility is getting set to true or not?

Comment: @Vishal Seth: Of course there is some content inside tr. Sorry for a bit incorrect sample.

Comment: FYI - jQuery won't return null if it doesn't find a match - it returns an empty array.

Answer (score 12):

I always set the style.display property to "" (empty string) to show a hidden table row:

```
var row = document.getElementById('row_id');
row.style.display = "";   // shows the row
```

To hide it again:

```
row.style.display = "none";   // hides the row
```

in jQuery , this would be:

```
$("#row_id").css("display", ""); // show the row
```

or

```
$("#row_id").css("display", "none");  // hides the row
```

IE doesn't seem to like the 'table-row' value for display. And 'block' is not correct, and it seems to screw up the display in other browsers sometimes.

Comment: Yep, setting display to empty string is the best way to go. BTW, while IE7 does not support `table-row`, IE8 does.  Also, `block` in Firefox definitely messes up the layout of a table while IE (7 or 8) does not.

Answer (score 5):

The first one should work.  Are you wrapping it in $(document).ready(function(){}); ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hiddenTr').show();
});
```

Comment: yeah...they are both correct.  I just didn't bother mentioning the second since the first accomplishes what he wants without any cross browser issues.

Answer (score 2):

You could try setting `display:auto`, but honestly, I've had nothing but trouble manually setting the display property for table rows/cells.

What I've found usually works is creating a CSS class called "hidden" that has `display:none`.  Rather than show()ing, I just remove that class.

Answer (score 1):

tried ?

```
 $('#hiddenTr').css('display','block');
```

Also, you should put in a `<TD></TD>` with something in it, at least a `&nbsp;` so the row is not collapsed by your browser client. Diffrent clients behave diffrently...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

CSS style

```
<style>
.hiddenTr {display: none;}  
</style>
```

HTML Table Content

```
<table>
  <tr class="hiddenTr">
    <td>Hidden Table Row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>Table Row</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Table Row</td></tr>
</table>
```

HTML button code

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
```

Include jQuery CDN

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Create a custom javascript function

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    $('.hiddenTr').toggle();
};
</script>
```