# Table row display none in Javascript not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a table and its like the following:

```
<table>
<tr>
............
<td>
  <span><img id="icon_open_<%=rstloadmsg.getInt("uidmessage")%>" src="icon_plus.png" style="display:inline-block" alt="O" onclick="readmsg(<%=rst.getInt("id")%>)" ></span>
..........
</table>
```

Then I am using JavaScript functions to open and close messages from that table:

```
//Read message

function readmsg(msgid) {
    document.getElementById("msg_body_" + msgid).style.display = "table-row";
    document.getElementById("msg_reply_body_" + msgid).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("icon_open_" + msgid).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("icon_close_" + msgid).style.display = "inline-block";
}

//Close message
function closemsg(msgid) {
    //window.alert(msgid);
    document.getElementById("msg_body_" + msgid).style.display = "none";
    //window.alert("1");
    document.getElementById("msg_reply_body_" + msgid).style.display = "none";
    //window.alert("2");                
    document.getElementById("icon_open_" + msgid).style.display = "inline-block";
    //window.alert("3");                        
    document.getElementById("icon_close_" + msgid).style.display = "none";
    //window.alert("4");                        
}
```

**Its working fine in all other browsers except IE**.

In IE the open message is working fine. But close is not working. I tried a lot. In other browsers When ever it reach `alert("1")`, it is closing. In IE not happening even if it reach `alert("4");` Don't know why it is not working. Please help me. Is it because I am using `style.display = "table-row";` . Please help me.

**Note IE version : 11.0.9600.16384**

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/5hksqx4L/)

Comment: Can you copy the generated html here? It is possible you have duplicate IDs or something else we do not see. Maybe create a Fiddle?

Comment: Try to use `style.display = ""` (empty string instead of `table-row`) to show the table row, look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548713/change-table-row-display-property)

Comment: most of the values are from database and I am populating those into table just like a table. That's the reason I did not created fiddle. Hope u understand.

Comment: @skobaljic let me check it

Comment: @Santhucool you can't get any help like this.. We can't guess what the problem is.. Even though you dynamically generate your data, you can create a fiddle with dummy data while keeping your generated DOM

Comment: @skobaljic tried .style.display = "" .still on close it is not closing

Comment: Than you will have to re-create the issue on Fiddle, guessing is done.

Comment: jsfiddle works in IE11 - can't see any issue

Comment: @freefaller check close message it is not closing in my case.

Comment: Exactly how are we supposed to help, when the fiddle you provide **works** and you cannot provide anything that allows us to replicate the issue?  (Also, when notifying users, don't put a space between the @ and the username.  And you can only have a single user in a comment.)

Comment: @freefaller fiddle not working in my IE.

Comment: Then we have a different definition of the phrase "not working"... you need to explain much more clearly exactly what you're expecting to happen, and what is actually happening - and if there are any errors in the console log of your browser development tools.  Until then, I'm outta here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81950/discussion-between-santhucool-and-freefaller).

Comment: In my case when I checked on IE in my fiddle when I click open it opens the body content and when I click close it is not closing the content.   Hope you understand my problem.

Comment: Do you have compatibility mode enabled?

Comment: Thank you guys. My IE version is little older version of 11. I updated IE and it working fine.